# Взаимосвязь ajax с php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно возвращать данные с php обработчика ajax-запросов? И как вообще правильно писать этот обработчик? Признаюсь, всегда просто возвращал данные через `echo`, но что-то мне подсказывает что это не совсем правильно.

Вот пример:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../lib/ajax.php",
        data: {send:act, login:login, password:password},
        cache: false,
        success: function(reply){
            alert(reply);
            if(reply == 'true'){
                $('.login-status').text('Ok');
                $('.login-status').fadeTo(0, 1);
                $('.login-status').fadeTo(4000, 0);
                $('[name = login]').val('');
                $('[name = password]').val('');
            }
        }
    })
```

Обработчик:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $login    = $POST_['login'];
        $password = $POST_['password'];
        ...
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Comment: Что подразумевается под правильным возвратом данных? `echo` ведь работает и даже, вроде как, не является костылём.

Comment: @Regent я всегда думал, что через `echo` не принято возвращать данные, а как-то по другому все делают.

Comment: Если, например, используется фреймворк (Yii и прочие), то там да, по-другому делают (хотя кто знает как сам Yii страницу отдаёт). А уж отдавать ли в формате простого текста, HTML, JSON или ещё каком-то - это от ситуации зависит. Хотя JSON часто является самым удобным вариантом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возвращайте данные в JSON формате. Для этого используйте json_encode.

Ваш код ajax запроса:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"../lib/ajax.php",
    data: {send:act, login:login, password:password},
    cache: false,
    success: function(reply){

        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(reply);

        if(res.login){
            $('.login-status').text('Ok');
            $('.login-status').fadeTo(0, 1);
            $('.login-status').fadeTo(4000, 0);
            $('[name = login]').val('');
            $('[name = password]').val('');
        } else {
            alert(res.error);
        }

    }
});
```

Ваш обработчик:

```
$res = array();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $login    = $POST_['login'];
    $password = $POST_['password'];

    if(логин и пароль не совпадают){
        $res['error'] = 'Логин или пароль введены неверно!'; 
    } else {
        ...
        ...            
        $res['login'] = true;
    }  

    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Comment: @alexkad, логичней добавить параметр `dataType: 'json'` в параметры аякса, нежели писать `var res = jQuery.parseJSON(reply);`

Comment: @mJeevas, согласен, можно и так.