# Ajax ответ от сервера

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Проблема заключается в том, что первый пользователь отправляет на `ajax` переменную, на сервере она обрабатывается функцией, и затем нужно вернуть результат в `javascript`. 
То-есть ответ нужен ТОЛЬКО если функция вернула нужный результат. 
Со всех моих попыток я понял, что `success()` в функции `$ajax` отрабатывает, когда переменная успешно отправилась. Подскажите, как можно реализовать передачу ответа не всегда, а только когда функция отработала? Заранее спасибо. Привожу код ниже.

jQuery:

```
$("#right_panel #window .user_panel .send_party").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var login = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "",
        success: function(data){
            // Получаем ответ с сервера с помощью ajax
            alert(data);
            alert(data.responseText);
        },
        data: {"login":login}
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $result3 = $this->room1_model->checkParty($_POST['login']);
    if($result3){
        echo $result3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте свой код. От сервера всегда ожидается ответ, даже если он возвращает 500, 403 и т.д., но это ответ.

Comment: Ответ возвращайте всегда, но выполняйте действия на стороне js только при ответе определенного формата. Как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430240/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-ajax-%D1%81-php#430248

Comment: success срабатывает только тогда, когда серверный файл успешно отработал. В случае возникновения ошибки сработает error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер всегда будет возвращать код 200, если не произошло ошибок. Вам нужно самому менять заголовок ответа сервера, если в ходе ваших условий не получили то, что хотели на стороне сервера.
Например можете установить заголовок:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
```

Тогда на стороне AJAX это будет fail, а не success