# Не работает изменение файла на хостинге

Tags: php, функции, hosting

Нужно при клике на кнопки изменять наполнение файла, клик по первой - перезапись в abc.php текста из abc1.php ("import"), клик по второй - "export".

Текст в файлах
abc.php "main"
abc1.php "import"
abc2.php "export"

Код обработки

```
<?php
function importfunc(){
$file1 = '/home/user/web-site.com/www/administrator/components/com_jshopping/importexport/compleximportexport/abc.php';
$file2 = '/home/user/web-site.com/www/administrator/components/com_jshopping/importexport/compleximportexport/abc1.php';

$file1cont2 = file_get_contents($file2, true, $context);

file_put_contents ($file1, $file1cont2);
}

function exportfunc(){
$file11 = '/home/user/web-site.com/www/administrator/components/com_jshopping/importexport/compleximportexport/abc.php';
$file22 = '/home/user/web-site.com/www/administrator/components/com_jshopping/importexport/compleximportexport/abc2.php';

$file1cont22 = file_get_contents($file22, true, $context);

file_put_contents ($file11, $file1cont22);
}
?>
```

Скрипт

```
<script>
function importconf(){
    alert("<?php importfunc(); ?>");
}
function exportconf(){
    alert("<?php exportfunc(); ?>");
}
</script>
```

Кнопки на странице

```
<button onclick="importconf()">Change import config</button>
<button onclick="exportconf()">Change export config</button>
```

Comment: Вы не сможете таким образом вызвать функции php из js. У вас importfunc() и exportfunc() исполняются в момент отдачи страницы пользователю по 1 разу и все.

Comment: Как можна решить проблему - вызов функции php по клику?

Comment: ajax использовать.

Comment: К сожалению не нашел вариантов вызова php-функции по клику

Comment: @Visman в целом про асинхронность никто не писал, так что не обязательно ajax, можно и обычную форму сделать.

Comment: Отправляете через ajax post-запрос на сервер к вашему файлу. В запросе отправляете переменную которая будет указывать какое действие хотите выполнить. На сервере в файле к которому идет пост запрос обрабатываете его, в зависимости от переменной выполняете ту или иную функцию и возвращаете ответ.

Comment: @teran, согласен, можно формой обойтись с перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: @Visman Хотя бы пример изменения файла через ajax post-запрос к файлу?

Comment: В этом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430248/186083 ответе есть пример взаимодействия js (jquery) с помощью ajax запроса с php. В php передаются две переменные login и password из js в php, в php проводится проверка и возвращается результат, в js обрабатывается результат. Русская документация по ajax (jquery) тут https://jquery-docs.ru/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Visman По ajax запроса вроде понятно, только как мне ajax запрос всунуть в onclick? Ведь если правильно понял то передача данных идет через строку "data: {send:act, login:login...."

Comment: В onclick у вас вызываются функции js, в них задавайте нужные параметры и с этими параметрами отправляйте ajax запрос на сервер.